How to SUM by parent table value while ignoring child table cardinality?
I am looking for a way to extract data with a single query and answering to two fundamental questions:

I want to be able to get details about a child table where I have to group by a column and SUM amounts, and
I want to keep a "global" sum from the parent table valid.

Suppose the following tables:
CREATE TABLE Invoice (
  Id        VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  Pax       INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE InvoiceLine (
  Id        VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
  InvoiceId VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  Activity  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  Amount    DECIMAL(19,4) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_InvoiceLine_InvoiceId FOREIGN KEY (InvoiceId) REFERENCES Invoice (Id)
)

And the following datas:
Invoice Table:



Id
Pax




001
2


002
2


003
4



InvoiceLine Table:



Id
InvoiceId
Activity
Amount




001
001
Ticketing
40.00


002
001
Reservation
10.00


003
002
Ticketing
30.00


004
002
Ticketing
30.00


005
002
Reservation
8.00


006
002
Insurance
6.60


007
003
Reservation
120.00


008
003
Reservation
40.00



    INSERT INTO Invoice VALUES ('001', 2);
    INSERT INTO Invoice VALUES ('002', 2);
    INSERT INTO Invoice VALUES ('003', 4);
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine VALUES ('001', '001', 'Ticketing',   40);
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine VALUES ('002', '001', 'Reservation', 10);
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine VALUES ('003', '002', 'Ticketing',   30);
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine VALUES ('004', '002', 'Ticketing',   30);
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine VALUES ('005', '002', 'Reservation',  8);
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine VALUES ('006', '002', 'Insurance',    6.6);
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine VALUES ('007', '003', 'Ticketing',  120);
    INSERT INTO InvoiceLine VALUES ('008', '003', 'Ticketing',   40);

My goal is to have a query to retrieve (in the same query):

Amount: sum of amount per activity
Pax: number of pax per activity
GlobalPax: number of pax served globally (sum = 8)

I have found a way to obtain the correct result, but it requires to group by i.Id, which increase the number of rows returned (in my case I have millions of rows).
SELECT
  i.Id,
  il.Activity,
  SUM(il.Amount) AS Amount,
  AVG(i.Pax) AS Pax,
  AVG(CAST(i.Pax AS float)) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY i.Id) AS GlobalPax
FROM
  Invoice AS i
  JOIN InvoiceLine AS il ON i.Id = il.InvoiceId
GROUP BY
  i.Id,
  il.Activity

Which gives me:



Id
Activity
Amount
Pax
GlobalPax




001
Reservation
10.0000
2
1


001
Ticketing
40.0000
2
1


002
Insurance
6.6000
2
0.666666666666667


002
Reservation
8.0000
2
0.666666666666667


002
Ticketing
60.0000
2
0.666666666666667


003
Ticketing
160.0000
4
4



The results is almost perfect, but I don't need the Id column (required for the PARTITION BY clause).
A perfect result could be:



Activity
Amount
Pax
GlobalPax




Insurance
6.6000
2
0.666666666666667


Reservation
18.0000
4
1.666666666666667


Ticketing
260.0000
8
5.666666666666667



Thanks

I don't understand the logic, what is GlobalPax supposed to represent?

Your table data doesn't seem to match the script nor the final result data (see ticketing vs reservation)

Here's a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/n5W2Ja6z which seems to achieve your final result (even though i don't really agree with those results :D)

My be Ticketing 360.0000 ->Ticketing 260.0000?

@Charlieface GlobalPax returns a correct SUM for all pax from Invoice table, without depending on the InvoiceLine table

@siggemannen Fixed, thanks

That could be, I just don't get the logic of how you are splitting up the Pax. For example what makes Reservation equal 1.666666. Also the Pax column in the result doesn't seem to match "number of pax per activity", should be 2 4 and 14

Please be Please be clear and explain the exact steps involved.

I want to be sure that despite each invoice are splitted in multiple lines, the sum of the column remains equals to the sum of the column in the invoice table.

@Charlieface The only solution for this is to split the number of pax by the number of rows returned by the JOIN with InvoiceLine. Eg: 2 pax must be divided by 3 in the case of invoice 002 (because there are two lines with the same activity, so 3 groups) which gives 0.66666. 2 pax divided by 2 in case of invoice 001 and 4 for invoice 003 (4 divided by 1 also because 2 rows have the same activity).
Then you group by activity and sum these results, which gives you the final table.

Oh OK then the query below gets you that result, but honestly I'm really not sure this result actually represents anything useful, and if it does then there is probably something very wrong with your database design. Summing an average just feels completely wrong.

You should apply next grouping by Activity, if don't need the Id column.
See example
select Activity
  ,sum(Amount) as Amount
  ,sum(Pax) as Pax
  ,sum(GlobalPax) as GlobalPax
from( -- your query
SELECT
  i.Id,
  il.Activity,
  SUM(il.Amount) AS Amount,
  AVG(i.Pax) AS Pax,
  AVG(CAST(i.Pax AS float)) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY i.Id) AS GlobalPax
FROM
  Invoice AS i
  JOIN InvoiceLine AS il ON i.Id = il.InvoiceId
GROUP BY i.Id, il.Activity
)a
group by Activity




Activity
Amount
Pax
GlobalPax




Insurance
6.6000
2
0.666666666666667


Reservation
18.0000
4
1.66666666666667


Ticketing
260.0000
8
5.66666666666667



fiddle

Thanks. I was hoping to not create a nested query, but it seems there is no choice.
